# Logrotate configuration: it works, but always keeps 'current' log empty

Tags: openvpn, logrotate

I moved logging for `openvpn` into its own log and attempted to set up log rotation for it, but I've obviously done something wrong.

Logging occurs as desired but always into the 2nd logfile`openvpn.log.1`.  The 'current' logfile `openvpn.log` exists, but is always empty.

```
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Apr 20 07:35 openvpn.log
-rw------- 1 root root  5411 Apr 20 07:58 openvpn.log.1
```

Here's my logrotate configuration file for openvpn.

```
/var/log/openvpn.log {
       daily
       rotate 7
       delaycompress
       compress
       notifempty
       missingok
}
```

The line in Openvpn's `server.conf` regarding logging is

`log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log`

What did I mess up?

Comment: Came across this page while looking for a solution to log rotation. Thanks for the info, but I think I found a better solution on the OpenVPN support pages:
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/logging-and-debug-flag-options-for-access-server/ They give step by step instructions for configuring log rotation, you may find it better than what is given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your service aware of log rotation. Some services may be killed with HUP signal some may need a full restart. It is possible that service opens the `openvpn.log` file, which is renamed to `openvpn.log.1`.

Try to add:

```
postrotate
    systemctl restart openvpn.service
endscript
```

I don't know exactly how your service is called, so my guess for `openvpn.service` may be wrong.

Comment: What do I add that to?

Comment: To logrotate configuration for openvpn. After missingok line would be just fine.

Comment: Ok, will try. Won't be able to confirm if it works until tomorrow. Upvoted.

Comment: This answer works, after a service restart it writes into the `openvpn.log` file.  So I'm accepting it.  But, I don't really want to restart the service every day, in case I happen to be using it then.  I will keep researching.

Comment: You have to tell service that log file has changed. Some services like apache accept HUP signal. For some you can use reload. Some you have to restart. Find out what can you do with your service.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this old post](https://sourceforge.net/p/openvpn/mailman/message/30527649/) on the openvpn-users mailing list :

> openvpn logging is done by redirecting stdout/stderr to the logfile

So the solution is to use the `copytruncate` option in the logrotate configuration:

> copytruncate
>
> Truncate the original log file to zero size in place
>   after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and
>   optionally creating a new one. It can be used when some program cannot
>   be told to close its logfile and thus might continue writing
>   (appending) to the previous log file forever. Note that there is a
>   very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so
>   some logging data might be lost. When this option is used, the create
>   option will have no effect, as the old log file stays in place.

This is what I have in my `/etc/logrotate.d/openvpn` file :

```
/var/log/openvpn.log {
    weekly
    rotate 12
    copytruncate
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```